# Listening Skill and understanding issue

Tags: listening-comprehension

I don't know at all what they say at 1:06 and 1:20 in this video:

https://youtu.be/nJFSxXEjsgM

Could anyone help?

Comment: Did you try the subtitles? Except from one word, which isn't recognized ("... verbreitet Optimismus"?), most words are pretty close, except for capitalization issues and sentence marks. Transcribing, what YT suggests, would have been helpful for users answering here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1:06
Christian Lindner: "Aber wir sind guter Dinge und kämpfen ja hier darum, dass es eine Schwarz-Gelbe Regierung in Kiel gibt und dafür stehen die Chancen im Augenblick sehr gut"

Translation: "But we are optimistic and are fighting here, that there may be a Black-Yellow Government in Kiel, and at the moment the Chances for that are very good"

Black-Yellow Government meaning a coalition of the FDP(The party of Christian Lindner, the speaker here, which has the color yellow. Basically Liberals) and the CDU(The Christian Democratic party, associated with black).

Kiel is a city in Schleswig-Holstein.

1:20
Citizen: "Joar, wahrscheinlich bleibt alles so beim alten"

Its not exactly perfect High German, but rather a Northern German way of speaking, which is hard to understand for German learners sometimes.

Translation: "Well, probably everything will stay the same [... Regarding the new Government]"

Joar comes from Ja(Yes) and is used like the English "Weeeeellll", if you know what I mean.

Comment: You are my unbelievable savior

Answer (score 1):

1:06: "[Wir]...kämpfen ja hier darum, daß es eine schwarz-gelbe Regierung in Kiel gibt".

1:20: "Jo, wahrscheinlich bleibt alles beim alten."

"Ja" ("Jo") is often used as an interjection without any meaning or grammatical function at all. Similar to "Hey" and "Yo", etc. in English. Just remove all these before parsing a sentence. In Lindners case he used it probably to buy him time to structure his answer while already talking so that nobody else has a chance to say something. Politicians are trained in those sorts of things and you can see that in full swing in every talk show.

The "schwarz-gelbe" refers to the party colours of CDU (black) and of the FDP (yellow). What he meant was a coalition of CDU and FDP, which he tries to accomplish.

"Kiel" is the capital and location of the government of Schleswig-Holstein. So, what he meant was: he is fighting to install a new government in Schleswig-Holstein in the form of a CDU-FDP coalition.

1:20 is just mumbling a bit. "(Es bleibt) alles beim alten." is a phrase meaning everything stays the same.

Comment: You are super for me!!